# Spawning threads from a gunicorn worker thread doesn't work

Tags: multithreading, gunicorn

I am aware that gunicorn allows for multiple worker processes and multiple threads within a process, in order to handle multiple requests simultaneously. That’s great.

What I’m trying to do, however, is within the context of handling one request. I want to spawn my own threads to allow for some parallel processing of different aspects of that request. This all works just fine if I run my program on its own – or in a unit test using Flask’s test client.

But when I try running under gunicorn (eventlet), I can still spawn those threads just fine, but they end up running in serial: the first one runs to conclusion, then the second one runs. Any idea of what might be going on?

Comment: Same problem here, with Gunicorn 19.9

Comment: Same problem here, any solutions ?